# Bar lines in lilypond

Tags: notation, lilypond

I want to control on the locations of the bar lines (yellow marked).
I want to move them to any other places when ever I would like to do. its seems to me that bar lines pop up automaticaly...

For example, see part of my code:

```
\relative {
  \key g \minor 
  \numericTimeSignature
  \time 4/4
  \fdo g'8 \ \bar "|"
  \fre d'4  \fre d4  \fsol g4, \fdo c4 \fdo c4 \fsol g4 \bar "|"
  \fsi b2.
}
```

[image]

Comment: Looking at your Lilypond code, it looks like what you want isn't 4/4 time (unlike your code), but 6/4 or 3/2 time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Kilian and Richard both say, you need to do two things:

1. Change the time signature to 6/4 (or 3/2)
2. Add a "partial" (because of the upbeat). This is an eighth note, so \partial 8

With these changes, Lilypond will automatically add bar lines in the correct places. You can add a "|" symbol to indicate that you think a bar line should go here (and Lilypond will check that it agrees).

Here's your example with these changes (omitting the fingering diagrams):

```
\version "2.22.1" % It should work with other versions too!
\language "english"

\relative {
  \key g \minor 
  \numericTimeSignature
  \time 6/4 % changed!
  \partial 8 % added!
  g'8 |
  d'4 d4 g,4 c4 c4 g4 |
  b2.
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The bar lines pop up wherever the time signature tells them to. If you want them in the correct places, use the right [`\time` signature](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.21/Documentation/notation/displaying-rhythms#time-signature) for your piece, and don't forget to use [`\partial`](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.21/Documentation/notation/displaying-rhythms#upbeats) if you have an upbeat.

Comment: The Lilypond code in the OP uses 4/4 time, though. How come the highlighted barlines aren't in the usual places for 4/4 time (pickup or no pickup)?

Answer (score 6):

As Kilian says, you'll need to change the time signature whenever you do so.

However, you can suppress the display of the time signature by including `\with { \omit TimeSignature }` in your Staff. For example, the following [snippet](https://lsr.di.unimi.it/LSR/Snippet?id=731) from the [LilyPond Snippet Repository](https://lsr.di.unimi.it/LSR/Search) shows how this can be done:

```
\new Staff \with { \omit TimeSignature } {
  \relative c'' {
    \time 3/4
    c4 c c
    \time 2/4
    c4 c
    \time 3/4
    c4 c c
    \time 2/4
    c4 c
    \time 5/4
    c4 c c c c
    \time 2/4
    c4 c
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: ok , relating to part of my code, how do I need to re-write it?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your full original code? That way I can more clearly shows what needs to happen.

Comment: \relative {
  \key g \minor 
  \numericTimeSignature
  \time 4/4
  \fdo g'8 \ \bar "|"
  \fre d'4  \fre d4  \fsol g4, \fdo c4 \fdo c4 \fsol g4 \bar "|"
  \fsi b2.
}

Comment: I can not reload the notes in comment mode but the image added at the begining of my question. Thank a lot.

Comment: please ignore to \fdo..\fre, those are woodwing functions...